# Definition of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

An elliptic curve over a field $K$ is defined as a 'genus $1$ curve with a base point'.

My question is, why don't we adopt the definition 'a smooth curve that is isomorphic to a degree $3$ smooth curve with a base point'?

I think these definitions are equivalent because a genus $1$ curve with a base point is isomorphic to the Weierstrass form over $K$, which is a degree $3$ smooth curve with a base point. On the other hand, every smooth curve that is isomorphic to a degree $3$ curve has a genus $\frac{(3-1)(3-2)}{2} = 1$.

What is the merit of defining elliptic curves as 'a genus $1$ curve with a base point' rather than as 'a smooth curve that is isomorphic to a degree $3$ smooth curve with a base point'?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In this case, "genus=1" is equivalent to being a degree 3 plane curve. The question seems to be regarding conventions: why emphasize one equivalent condition over another.

Comment: The genus is a cohomological invariant, so it's easier to carry around. In your definition I can see many cases when you're would need to be careful if the isomorphism is also part of the data, and if it's not, how do you work with morphisms of your objects?

Comment: Indeed, to make your definition truly an equivalence of categories, you're using the data $(E, O, \phi : E \to C)$ where $C$ is a plane cubic. A morphism is then the data of a $\psi \colon E \to E'$ so that $\psi(O) = O'$ and another morphism $\Psi : C \to C'$ such that $\phi' \psi = \Psi \phi$... can you see why this would be annoying.

Comment: Sometimes (for example in certain crypto applications) they may prefer a degree four curve with a singularity on the line at infinity and a base point (look up hyperelliptic curves). That is still an elliptic curve, because it has genus $1$ and that base point. As the others said, genus is a better behaving invariant. Admittedly, there isn't an awful lot into it. Also, the standard proof (may be just *a* standard proof) for the existence of a Weierstrass form equation uses Riemann-Roch, **and the genus**. So...

Comment: Without even knowing much about this subject, I would emphasize the general methodology of classification theorems in mathematics: define objects by their intrinsic properties (e.g. genus 1 curves with a base point); and then give an extrinsic classification of all such objects (e.g. those curves that are isomorphic to some degree 3 smooth curve with a base point).